# Getting Closure / Plovr to remove functions from an if that is always false

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, plovr

An if statement that is obviously always false, eg. `if (false)`, closure removes the statement.

My code looks like this:

```
if (settings.lang === "en"){
    lib.doSomething();
}
```

`settings.lang` is a constant.

```
/** 
 * @type {string}
 * @const 
 */ 
settings.lang = "fr" ;
```

So when it equals "fr" the compiler could remove the `if` and the definition of `lib.doSomething` at compile time. But it doesn't. Is there any way to get it to do that?

Before you ask why I don't just delete that code: for other clients, `settings.lang` **is** set to `en`.

Comment: what is your compilation level? have you tried passing it as a @define?

Comment: And you may have to show more of your source code. A quick check at closure-compiler.appspot.com shows that the optimization you are after works as expected.

Comment: I thought define might be the answer. I define goog.DEBUG, but goog.LANG throws a plovr warning. I can;t find documentation on using @define for custom properties.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler @define instead of @constant. You give it a value in code and can override it in the compiler with `--define='YOUR_DEFINE=false'` What kind of warning does plovr give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Make sure "settings" is properly defined:

```
/** @const */
var settings = {};
```

2) Make sure "settings" lang is properly defined:

```
/** @const */ 
settings.lang = "fr" ;
```

3) Make sure the value is referenced after it is defined:

```
if (settings.lang == "en") ...
```

In advanced mode this will be inlined and removed, if settings is not used in a way that prevents property collapsing (for instance, passing "settings" as a parameter to a function will cause the value to escape and be uncollapsible).

This is simplified, if you use @define:

```
/** @const */
var settings = {};

/** @define {string} */
settings.lang = "fr";
```

You should get a warning if the definition of the define is not valid in some way.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using some compilation mode (most likely the `'SIMPLE'` compilation mode, as that is [the default in plovr](http://plovr.com/options.html#mode)) other than the `'ADVANCED'` compilation mode. The advanced compilation mode [is the one that does dead code removal](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/compilation_levels).

Comment: I'm using `ADVANCED`. It's just not identifying it as dead code.

Answer (score 1):

Is goog.LANG defined with goog.define?  Last I checked Plovr was not compatible with goog.define (it doesn't have the latest compiler) make sure you are starting with a compatible version of the Closure Library.